# Importing function from Python script hosted on Github

Tags: python, function, import

Is there a simply way to download/save a Python script hosted on Github and then import a function within that script? I could manually save it and then import the function I need (of course), but I'd like to find a more self-contained solution. Ideally, I'd like to be able to send it to someone and have them run my script without having to manually download anything.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`setuptools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) and write custom [`setup`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/setup.py) script for your package. Wrap your script into python package.

So users will be able install it via `pip` with just a single line:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/yournickname/reponame.git
```